# AWS Lambda with Cognito timeout if not called 1 day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I use the Serverless framework to deploy my code - AWS CodePipeline which listen for changes in AWS CodeCommit repo and deploys by executing a command like this `sls deploy -v -s $ENV_NAME`.
It creates API Gateway endpoint and Lambda for login using AWS Cognito SDK.
I test the login endpoint locally and on AWS and it works fine. On the next day I test endpoint again (without any config and code change) and locally it works fine but when I call it on AWS I get timeout, again and again. No error in the log (CloudWatch) just 'Task timed out after 17.02 seconds'. If I go in the Lambda on AWS and just add `console.log("Hello")` it starts to work as expected! It happens the same with other endpoints that use Cognito to manage users. Another endpoints which not to Cognito work as expected.
Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: So every time you deploy, it work. Then you testing it the following day, and you get timeout errors until you add a console.log message which fixes it after that. This happens EVERY time you re-deploy. Is that correct?? 
So far, it sounds like a race condition and the `console.log` adds enough delay for your asynchronous calls to finish executing.

Comment: @flz After deploy it works. For example if I change serverless.yml file all Lambdas start to work but if I add something only in given Lambda then only this function starts to work! It think is not because of delay that console.log() adds, because locally the code works fine. So it's really weird and I still research details